# What does this Windows 2008 Debug output mean

Tags: c#, .net, windows, debugging, networking

I have a Windows 2008 R2 Virtual production machine, with VMWare tools installed. I have installed my .NET 4 windows service on the machine which does 10 to 20 HttpWebRequests every minute. I was looking at DebugView, and I see the following log. Once that kind of log shows up in debugview, my app stops working. It's still in memory without any exceptions logged ( I have enough logging in place). But, it's doing nothing as far as I can see.

If anybody can interpret or guess what's this saying that will be beneficial. Only part I understand here is Wsk means WinSock Kernel!

```
[FFFFFA800471C010] WskProIRPGetAddrInfo is called.  
[bind=FFFFFA8003829C10] Binding reference count++ = 2 (status = 00000000, impersonation= 2).  
[FFFFFA80046B3170] Request reference count++ = 3.  
[FFFFFA80046B3170] RPC method type = 1: rpc-method succeeded, queue to rpc-pending-list.  
[FFFFFA80046B3170] Request reference count-- = 2.  
[FFFFFA80046B3170] WskKnrRpcComplete: rpc calls back for completion.  
[FFFFFA80046B3170] WskKnrCompletePending: complete pending request (rpc=1).  
[FFFFFA80046B3170] Request reference count-- = 1.  
[FFFFFA80046B3170] Request reference count-- = 0.  
[FFFFFA80046B3170] WskKnrCompleteRequest: rpc completion return status = 00000000 (reply=00000000).  
[FFFFFA80046B3170] WskProAPIGetAddressInfo returned addrinfo: [addr=FFFFF8A00C199A50].  
[bind=FFFFFA8003829C10] Binding reference count-- = 1.  
[FFFFFA80046B3170] WskKnrCompleteRequest: complete irp with IO status = 00000000.  
[addr=FFFFF8A00C199A50] WskProAPIFreeAddressInfo freed addrinfo.  
[FFFFFA80049EA680] WskProIRPGetAddrInfo is called.  
[bind=FFFFFA8003829C10] Binding reference count++ = 2 (status = 00000000, impersonation= 2).  
[FFFFFA8004564C00] Request reference count++ = 3.  
[FFFFFA8004564C00] WskKnrRpcComplete: rpc calls back for completion.  
[FFFFFA8004564C00] WskKnrCompletePending: complete pending request (rpc=1).  
[FFFFFA8004564C00] Request reference count-- = 2.  
[FFFFFA8004564C00] Request reference count-- = 1.  
[FFFFFA8004564C00] RPC method type = 1: rpc-method succeeded, queue to rpc-pending-list.  
[FFFFFA8004564C00] Request reference count-- = 0.  
[FFFFFA8004564C00] WskKnrCompleteRequest: rpc completion return status = 00000000 (reply=00000000).  
[FFFFFA8004564C00] WskProAPIGetAddressInfo returned addrinfo: [addr=FFFFF8A00731B680].  
[bind=FFFFFA8003829C10] Binding reference count-- = 1.  
[FFFFFA8004564C00] WskKnrCompleteRequest: complete irp with IO status = 00000000.  
[FFFFFA80049732E0] WskProIRPGetAddrInfo is called.  
[bind=FFFFFA8003829C10] Binding reference count++ = 2 (status = 00000000, impersonation= 2).  
[FFFFFA8003D53670] Request reference count++ = 3.  
[FFFFFA8003D53670] RPC method type = 1: rpc-method succeeded, queue to rpc-pending-list.  
[FFFFFA8003D53670] Request reference count-- = 2.  
[FFFFFA8003D53670] WskKnrRpcComplete: rpc calls back for completion.  
[FFFFFA8003D53670] WskKnrCompletePending: complete pending request (rpc=1).  
[FFFFFA8003D53670] Request reference count-- = 1.  
[FFFFFA8003D53670] Request reference count-- = 0.  
[FFFFFA8003D53670] WskKnrCompleteRequest: rpc completion return status = 00000000 (reply=00000000).  
[FFFFFA8003D53670] WskProAPIGetAddressInfo returned addrinfo: [addr=FFFFF8A00D32D600].  
[bind=FFFFFA8003829C10] Binding reference count-- = 1.  
[FFFFFA8003D53670] WskKnrCompleteRequest: complete irp with IO status = 00000000.  
[addr=FFFFF8A00731B680] WskProAPIFreeAddressInfo freed addrinfo.  
[addr=FFFFF8A00D32D600] WskProAPIFreeAddressInfo freed addrinfo.  
KTM:  TmCommitTransaction for tx 4aba720  
KTM:  Notifying RM of 1 for tx 4aba720  
KTM:  TmPrepareTransaction for en 475cbc0  
KTM:  Notifying RM of 16 for tx 4a07060  
KTM:  Notifying RM of 2 for tx 4aba720  
KTM:  TmPrepareTransaction for en 475cbc0  
KTM:  Notifying RM of 2 for tx 4a07060  
KTM:  Notifying RM of 32 for tx 4a07060  
KTM:  TmRollbackEnlistment for tx 4a07060  
KTM:  Notifying RM of 2 for tx 4aba720  
KTM:  Notifying RM of 4 for tx 4aba720  
KTM:  TmCommitTransaction for tx 4a07060  
KTM:  Notifying RM of 64 for tx 4a07060  
KTM:  TmRollbackEnlistment for tx 4a07060  
KTM:  TmRollbackEnlistment for tx 4aba720  
KTM:  TmRollbackTransaction for tx 4a07060  
KTM:  TmRollbackEnlistment for tx 4aba720  
KTM:  TmRollbackTransaction for tx 4aba720  
[2344] Trace Start:0End Index:8   
[2344] Trace Start:0End Index:8   
KTM:  TmCommitTransaction for tx 4b2c610  
KTM:  Notifying RM of 1 for tx 4b2c610  
KTM:  TmPrepareTransaction for en 48643d0  
KTM:  Notifying RM of 16 for tx 4a6e250  
KTM:  Notifying RM of 2 for tx 4b2c610  
KTM:  TmPrepareTransaction for en 48643d0  
KTM:  Notifying RM of 2 for tx 4a6e250  
KTM:  Notifying RM of 32 for tx 4a6e250  
KTM:  Notifying RM of 2 for tx 4b2c610  
KTM:  Notifying RM of 4 for tx 4b2c610  
KTM:  TmCommitTransaction for tx 4a6e250  
KTM:  Notifying RM of 4 for tx 4a6e250  
KTM:  Notifying RM of 64 for tx 4a6e250  
KTM:  TmRollbackEnlistment for tx 4a6e250  
KTM:  TmRollbackEnlistment for tx 4b2c610  
KTM:  TmRollbackTransaction for tx 4a6e250  
KTM:  TmRollbackEnlistment for tx 4a6e250  
KTM:  TmRollbackEnlistment for tx 4b2c610  
KTM:  TmRollbackTransaction for tx 4b2c610  
[FFFFFA800477E5D0] WskProIRPGetAddrInfo is called.  
[bind=FFFFFA8003829C10] Binding reference count++ = 2 (status = 00000000, impersonation= 2).  
[FFFFFA8003C95510] Request reference count++ = 3.  
[FFFFFA8003C95510] RPC method type = 1: rpc-method succeeded, queue to rpc-pending-list.  
[FFFFFA8003C95510] Request reference count-- = 2.  
[FFFFFA8003C95510] WskKnrRpcComplete: rpc calls back for completion.  
[FFFFFA8003C95510] WskKnrCompletePending: complete pending request (rpc=1).  
[FFFFFA8003C95510] Request reference count-- = 1.  
[FFFFFA8003C95510] Request reference count-- = 0.  
[FFFFFA8003C95510] WskKnrCompleteRequest: rpc completion return status = 00000000 (reply=00000000).  
[FFFFFA8003C95510] WskProAPIGetAddressInfo returned addrinfo: [addr=FFFFF8A00D297510].  
[bind=FFFFFA8003829C10] Binding reference count-- = 1.  
[FFFFFA8003C95510] WskKnrCompleteRequest: complete irp with IO status = 00000000.  
[addr=FFFFF8A00D297510] WskProAPIFreeAddressInfo freed addrinfo.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WSK log is jut information. There is not error reproted by it. All the IRP are successfully completed. KTM(Kerne Transaction Manager) log says that it rolled back two transaction, I didn't get what transaction, becasue it may be your app specific.